# UBuntu BASh commands ls

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

i want to list files from dev end at tty bettwen 15 and 24...should appears /dev/tty15,/dev/tty16,/dev/tty17, etc until /dev/tty24

what is the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use Bash's brace expansion:

```
ls /dev/tty{15..24}
```

Comment: already try ls /dev/tty[15-24], but appear /dev/tty1 and i want that start on 15

Comment: @pedro: {} is different from [].

Comment: @pedro: That's a different expression. What that does is similar to a character regular expression. Have you tried the brace expansion instead?

Answer (score 0):

`ls /dev/tty{15..24}`?